# Parsing a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression which looks like this
Buddy(value,value,value) where value can be '(' or  ')' or even ','. I am trying to parse this regex but I am facing an issue in parsing if the regex is like- Buddy(,,,) or Buddy(),),)) these examples are considered as a valid regex.
my scanner gives me token like for example-Buddy(,,,)=Buddy ( , , , ). scanner will give token for everything that comes its way except empty spaces.Can anyone suggest a appropriate grammer/logic to parse this type of regex.

My code:

```
private void Parser() { 
    //lookahead is a global variable that contains the next token value
    //match increments the token to next 
    // This seems to work for Buddy(a,b,c) match(Token.Kind.Buddy);

    match(Token.Kind.LeftParenthesis); 
    match(Token.Kind.Value); 
    while(_lookahead.Kind!=Token.Kind.RightParenthesis) { 
        Recursive(); 
    } 
    match(Token.Kind!=RightParenthesis) } private void Recursive() { 
    match(Token.Kind.Comma); 
    match(Token.Kind.Value); 
}
```

Comment: can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: private void Parser() {
      //lookahead is a global variable that  contains the next token value
      //match increments the token to next
      // This seems to work for Buddy(a,b,c)
  match(Token.Kind.Buddy); 
  match(Token.Kind.LeftParenthesis);
  match(Token.Kind.Value);
  while(_lookahead.Kind!=Token.Kind.RightParenthesis)
  {
   Recursive();
  }
  match(Token.Kind!=RightParenthesis)
  
  }
  
  private void Recursive()
  {
  match(Token.Kind.Comma);
  match(Token.Kind.Value);
  }

Comment: No. First [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), then [ask], then apply the advice by editing your post.